# Interpreting survival analysis plot using genes as predictor

Tags: survival, lasso

I will show what I'm doing it in R to make sure if I'm doing it correctly

This is my dataset which I'm using for analysis

```
 dput(df2)
structure(list(TCGA_ID = c("TCGA-AB-2965", "TCGA-AB-2881", "TCGA-AB-2834", 
"TCGA-AB-2818", "TCGA-AB-2898", "TCGA-AB-2956", "TCGA-AB-2994", 
"TCGA-AB-2920", "TCGA-AB-3009", "TCGA-AB-2892", "TCGA-AB-2814", 
"TCGA-AB-2891", "TCGA-AB-2991", "TCGA-AB-2875", "TCGA-AB-2805", 
"TCGA-AB-3007", "TCGA-AB-2884", "TCGA-AB-2975", "TCGA-AB-2946", 
"TCGA-AB-2932", "TCGA-AB-2979", "TCGA-AB-2917", "TCGA-AB-2828", 
"TCGA-AB-2867", "TCGA-AB-2815", "TCGA-AB-2839", "TCGA-AB-2928", 
"TCGA-AB-2980", "TCGA-AB-2873", "TCGA-AB-2853", "TCGA-AB-2976", 
"TCGA-AB-2877", "TCGA-AB-3001", "TCGA-AB-3012", "TCGA-AB-2940", 
"TCGA-AB-2992", "TCGA-AB-2806", "TCGA-AB-2995", "TCGA-AB-2847", 
"TCGA-AB-2842", "TCGA-AB-2858", "TCGA-AB-2987", "TCGA-AB-2856", 
"TCGA-AB-2916", "TCGA-AB-2901", "TCGA-AB-2844", "TCGA-AB-2808", 
"TCGA-AB-2955", "TCGA-AB-2820", "TCGA-AB-2811", "TCGA-AB-2835", 
"TCGA-AB-2930", "TCGA-AB-2845", "TCGA-AB-2893", "TCGA-AB-2942", 
"TCGA-AB-2921", "TCGA-AB-2988", "TCGA-AB-3002", "TCGA-AB-2925", 
"TCGA-AB-2943", "TCGA-AB-2959", "TCGA-AB-2933", "TCGA-AB-2939", 
"TCGA-AB-2866", "TCGA-AB-2813", "TCGA-AB-2896", "TCGA-AB-3008", 
"TCGA-AB-2950", "TCGA-AB-2819", "TCGA-AB-2895", "TCGA-AB-2830", 
"TCGA-AB-2812", "TCGA-AB-2918", "TCGA-AB-2915", "TCGA-AB-2869", 
"TCGA-AB-2948", "TCGA-AB-2931", "TCGA-AB-2924", "TCGA-AB-2935", 
"TCGA-AB-2836", "TCGA-AB-2970", "TCGA-AB-2900", "TCGA-AB-2936", 
"TCGA-AB-2934", "TCGA-AB-2952", "TCGA-AB-2927", "TCGA-AB-2817", 
"TCGA-AB-2949", "TCGA-AB-2914", "TCGA-AB-2996", "TCGA-AB-2885", 
"TCGA-AB-2882", "TCGA-AB-2825", "TCGA-AB-2823", "TCGA-AB-2888", 
"TCGA-AB-2919", "TCGA-AB-2890", "TCGA-AB-2984", "TCGA-AB-2897", 
"TCGA-AB-2865", "TCGA-AB-2983", "TCGA-AB-2841"), turqoise_module = c("High", 
"Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "Low", 
"High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", 
"Low", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
"High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
"Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", 
"Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low"), OS_MONTHS = c(11.3, 
29.7, 7.7, 10.2, 36.1, 5.7, 83.5, 11.8, 19, 59.3, 26.3, 21.5, 
88.3, 27.7, 18.5, 75.8, 24.8, 34, 24.4, 42.1, 47, 57.3, 99.9, 
5.2, 26.3, 16.3, 4, 47.5, 32.7, 3.1, 30, 41.4, 76.2, 86.6, 55.4, 
56.3, 30.6, 73.6, 52.7, 0.3, 19.2, 6.3, 5.3, 45.3, 10.5, 3.9, 
118.1, 16.4, 0.3, 8.2, 77.3, 7.1, 9.3, 6.6, 43.5, 8.1, 0.8, 46.8, 
7.9, 4.2, 15.4, 4.6, 36.9, 5.5, 1.3, 7.5, 27, 40.3, 95.6, 5.7, 
8.1, 11.5, 7.4, 0.5, 27.1, 18.1, 0.1, 26, 1.6, 17, 10.7, 6.3, 
13.8, 6.6, 1.9, 2.4, 9.3, 32.6, 48.3, 73, 7, 11, 7.5, 0.2, 33.5, 
26.8, 0.5, 71.3, 30.5, 2.3, 11.2, 46.5), Status = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -102L), class = "data.frame")
```

Where the turqoise_module was obtained based on the a signature of 31 genes which I was able to get based on the explanation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/610125/using-multiple-genes-building-gene-signature-and-survival-analysis/610284?noredirect=1#comment1133081_610284)

Now what I do next is this

```
fit1 = survfit(Surv(OS_MONTHS, Status)~ turqoise_module, data=df2)
fit1
out1 = survdiff(Surv(OS_MONTHS, Status)~ turqoise_module, data=df2)
out1
```

The output of the above model fitting is this

```
fit1
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(OS_MONTHS, Status) ~ turqoise_module, 
    data = df2)

                      n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
turqoise_module=High 51     48    7.1     5.7     8.2
turqoise_module=Low  51     17     NA    55.4      NA
> out1
Call:
survdiff(formula = Surv(OS_MONTHS, Status) ~ turqoise_module, 
    data = df2)

                      N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
turqoise_module=High 51       48     18.4      47.7      74.7
turqoise_module=Low  51       17     46.6      18.8      74.7

 Chisq= 74.7  on 1 degrees of freedom, p= <2e-16
```

When i plot them using this code

```
ggsurvplot(fit1,
           pval = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE,data = df2,
           risk.table = TRUE, # Add risk table
           risk.table.col = "strata", # Change risk table color by groups
           linetype = "strata", # Change line type by groups
           surv.median.line = "hv", # Specify median survival
           ggtheme = theme_bw(base_size = fsize),
           palette = c("#990000", "#000099","green","black"))
```

I get this output [image: train data survival]

Now to obtain the turquoise_module based on which I categorized high or low I have used this code

```
df1 <- x_te[,gene]
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)

df1$LSC22score <- rowSums(
  sweep(x = df1, 
        MARGIN = 2,  
        STATS = beta1, 
        FUN = `*`)
)
df1 <- df1 %>% dplyr::mutate(turqoise_module = 
                             dplyr::case_when(
                               LSC22score > median(LSC22score) ~ "High",
                               LSC22score < median(LSC22score) ~ "Low"
                             ))
```

Now my question is when I see the `out1` output and the figure generate there is bit of confusion due to my lack of conceptual clarity.

**

> The expected number of deaths in the high turqoise module group is
> 18.4, while the observed number of deaths is 48, indicating that there are more deaths in this group than expected. The opposite is true for
> the low turqoise module group, where the observed number of deaths is
> 17 while the expected number is 46.6, suggesting that there are fewer
> deaths in this group than expected.

**

But when I see the figure the I thought patient categorized as low are surviving for longer period of time.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated how to interpret or where am I going wrong

Comment: I don't see a problem. If O/E is over 1 then the risk is higher and theer are more deaths than expected. Conversely if O/E is low then the risk is lower than expected. Maybe you should expand on what you find troubling?

Comment: how do i interpret the graph I plotted my whether patients with  turquoise_low survive longer time or the turquoise_high? who survives longer

Comment: Each decrement in the line is a death. In the red line they are coming rapidly in the early times. Very few survive to time=30. So it is the low group that survives longer.

Comment: my confusion was with the survfit() output vs the graph ..

Comment: Again ::: unless you express your confusion in an expanded way I cannot tell what erroneous assumptions you are making. The graph and the output appear consistent to my understanding.

Comment: okay the confusion was with this `out1` output which is the `survdiff` output which I have quoted in the expected vs observed and the graph where i see the turqoise_low are have more survival i was not able to understand the numbers are risk shown in ggsurvplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those in the `turquoise_low` group survive longer, as the plot shows and as you interpret the plot. I think that the confusion is from the way that the log-rank test performed by `survdiff()` is explained.

The "expected" number of deaths for the log-rank test in each `turquoise` group in your quotation is the number expected *if there were no survival difference between the groups*. That's the null hypothesis for the test. The calculation is a bit tricky in detail, outlined [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/577140/28500).

So if there are more deaths in one group and fewer in the other than "expected" based on the null hypothesis, that's evidence for a survival difference between the groups. That's what these data show.

Comment: `I think that the confusion is from the way that the log-rank test performed by survfit() is explained.` yes which seems counter intuitive what was plotted

Comment: so do i need to report the `survdiff()` output? along with the survival what i have seen in journals is they only describe that survival curve

Comment: @PesKchan The observed/expected count table is unnecessary, the log-rank p-value is sufficient for publication. Also common to show the KM plot itself, and possibly a CoxPH hazard ratio and p-value.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie thank you all for the insight and clarification these concepts

Comment: @PesKchan a general warning about this type of survival analysis based on gene expression: there's a risk that the gene-expression values are just recapitulating some already known outcome-associated clinical factors. For publication, it's important to show that the gene-expression data adds something useful to the clinical factors in terms of prognostication. Also, the arbitrary cutoff at the median of the gene-expression score, although perhaps useful for data display, is generally unwise for a prediction model. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/28500) among others.

Comment: `is generally unwise for a prediction model.` what is the other way you would like to suggest?

Comment: @PesKchan using a regression spline for the continuous score often is a good choice. See Chapter 2 of Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg.html), especially Section 2.4.

Comment: thank you for pointing the exact resources hopefully i can understand and try to use it as other way so far all the maths inside it looks terrifying